# Dynamically Extending a Model with a static method

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

in the plugin that I develop, I need to dynamically extend the model of another plugin with a static method. I have no idea how to do it.

In my plugin, I have a course session object that inherits from Jiri/JKShop/Models/product

In the jiri_jkshop_products table, I added an is_course field.

Before creating a product object, I would like to know if it is a course product or not in the following way:

```
if (\Jiri\JKShop\Models\Product::isCourse($productJson["product_id"])) {
    $product = \PluginAuthor\PluginName\Models\Session::find($productJson["product_id"]);
} else {
    $product = \Jiri\JKShop\Models\Product::find($productJson["product_id"]);
}
```

Please, how to dynamically add a static method to product model in the plugin.php file of my plugin?

I hope this idea corresponds to elegant code, if you have better, I take too

thank you in advance & regards,
Patrick

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `__callStatic()` magic method? It will be called if you call a static method on an object that doesn't actually have that method progammatically set. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Comment: thanks Denis, its a nice feature but my purpose is to not modify the product model directly (i want it keep his integrity) but dynamicaly in my plugin.php boot function

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with the extendable trait in the boot method of your plugin, something like this.

You can take advantage of laravel container to register a singleton to get always he same instance and i think it's a nice approach

```php
<?php
class YourPlugin extends PluginBase
{
   public function register()
   {
    $this->app->singleton('my.product', function () {
        return new \Jiri\JKShop\Models\Product;
    });
   }

   public function boot()
   {
    \Jiri\JKShop\Models\Product:::extend(function ($product) {
        $product->addDynamicMethod('isCourse', function ($course) use ($product) {
            return $product->find($course)->is_course;
        });
    });
   }
}
```

And now wherever you want in your plugin you can use your new dynamically added method

```php
<?php
if(app()->make('my.product')->isCourse($productJson["product_id"])){
    $product = \PluginAuthor\PluginName\Models\Session::find($productJson["product_id"]);
}else{
    $product = \Jiri\JKShop\Models\Product::find($productJson["product_id"]);
}
```

Comment: thanks OSdev, it's nice but in that way, you need to create a product object to test the is_course field. It works but I do not find it very elegant, I may be wrong. This means that you create a object first to test the field, then recreate it a second time or forget it to created the good one. this is what i did first but after thinking, i found the idea to add dynamicaly a static method with the same way you indicate to add the is_course method but static But is this possible ? :-)

Comment: You can't "i think" but what about a singleton object? i edited my answer

Comment: honestly i don't know :-)

Comment: Your solution is ingenious but I was looking for something lighter so I made a simple sql request on the course_id field with my poduct_id. Anyway thank you very much, regards